# django how can i get the request before the main urls.py

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

in django i got

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("something/", include("something.urls")),
    path("something2/", include("something2.urls")),
]
```

i want to see details about the request before they come to "urlpatterns"

i want to get the request object to see the ip everytime in all the urls and not metter when he want to go even if he go to "http://mywebsite.com/blablabla"

i want to see the request and be able to send him back status 400 if i dont like this ip

also i want to send all the requests to a statistic.py and analyze all the request to see stuff like if they got cookie and see the META of the request how can i achieve this?

Comment: You do this with middleware.

Comment: You don't do this before "anyone" comes to urlpatterns since that happens before any request anyway. As @WillemVanOnsem says, Django middleware is capable of intercepting all requests that come to your app.

Comment: If you do need to do this for certain views only, you could do this with view decorators (such as the stock `login_required()` does).

Answer (score 1):

You do this with *middleware*. Middleware is a stack of decorators where the request passes to, *before* and *after* accessing the view. You can make simple middleware as [described in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware). In fact you probably are already using a lot of middleware. the `.user` of `request.user` is added through middleware on the request object. A simple logger of the urls visited for example can look like:

```
# app_name/middleware.py

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('name_of_my_logger')

def logging_middleware(get_response):
    # One-time configuration and initialization.
    def middleware(request):
        logger.info(request.build_absolute_uri())
        response = get_response(request)
        return response
    return middleware
```

Here `get_response` is the decorator that is a level deeper. This is thus the next middleware layer, and eventually the view. You add this to the [**`MIDDLEWARE`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIDDLEWARE):

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # …,
    'app_name.middleware.logging_middleware',
    # …
]
```

By default there is already a lot of middleware that checks for csrf-tokens, adds `.user` to the request, etc. If you construct a Django project with `django-admin startproject`, then [by default there is a set of middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/):

> ```
> MIDDLEWARE = [
>     'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
>     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
>     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
> ]
> ```

You can look up the source code of such mixins, for example the [**`AuthenticationMiddleware`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L17-L23).

Comment: ty :) this is very helpful

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, you should accept it :)